# How can I determine if a template parameter is defaulted or not?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I have this simplified class (many details omitted) :

```cpp
template<class T, size_t nChunkSize = 1000>
class Holder
{
    size_t m_nSize = 0;
    size_t m_nChunkSize = nChunkSize;

public:
    Holder(size_t nSize)
        : m_nSize(nSize)
    {
    }

    size_t GetChunkSize()
    {
        return m_nChunkSize;
    }

    T* GetChunk(size_t nChunkIndex)
    {
        // returns the address of the chunk nChunkIndex
        return ###;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t nIndex)
    {
        // returns the element with index nIndex
        return T();
    }
};
```

The idea is to have a simple memory manager that allocates really large number of objects but if there is not enough memory to hold all objects in one place it splits them in chunks and encapsulates everything. I know I should use STL but I have specific reasons to do it this way.

I want to provide the users the ability to specify the chunk size and be able to get a pointer to a specific chunk but only if they have specified the template parameter otherwise I want that functionality to be disabled at compile time.

I know the compiler should know whether **nChunkSize** is defaulted or user specified but is there a way I can get that information and use it to delete **GetChunk** function or make it's usage not compilable.

For example:

```cpp
Holder<int, 200> intHolder(5000); // allocates 5000 integeres each chunk holds 200 of them

intHolder[312] = 2;
int* pChunk = intHolder.GetChunk(3); // OK, Compiles

Holder<int> intAnotherHolder(500); // allocates 500 but chunk size is hidden/implementation defined
pChunk = intAnotherHolder.GetChunk(20); // COMPILE ERROR
```

Comment: What does `operator()` do here: `pChunk = intAnotherHolder(20)`? Or should it be `pChunk = intAnotherHolder.GetChunk(20)`?

Comment: You want to differentiate `Holder<int>` from `Holder<int, 1000>` (where `1000` is the default) whereas there are the same type.

Comment: Yes. Thenk you - corrected

Comment: I wan differentiate between Holder<T> and Holder<T, something> even if that something is the default value. 

basically I want to disable parts of the functionality depending on if the template is the defaulted or the user have specified it.

Comment: @DimitarMirchev "Default value" means "if no value is specified for `nChunkSize`, act as if a value of `1000` was specified". If that's not what you want, then what you want is not a default value. (This may seem like pointless quibbling, but I don't think it is. Understanding it should change the way you look at the problem you're having.)

Comment: You could go for the solution of @TartanLlama but you still would not get different behaviour for explicitly using the flag value `Holder<T, std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()>` versus the defaulted behaviour of `Holder<T>`. The very thing you're asking fo is not possible.

Comment: Do you want to detect the value 1000, which is the default, or *must* you distinguish between default 1000 and user passing 1000?  Because the second seems strsnge, but is what you asked.

Comment: I guess I want some thing like: std::is_defaulted<nChunkSize>::value that returns true if the template was instantiated as Holder<int> but I guess that was a stretch

Answer (score 3):

You could use a common base class with two derived classes: one that specializes for the scenario where a `size_t` is provided, and another where one is not provided:

Base (Basically your current class):

```
template<typename T, size_t nChunkSize=1000>
class Base
{
    size_t m_nSize = 0;
    size_t m_nChunkSize = nChunkSize;

public:
    Base(size_t nSize)
        : m_nSize(nSize)
    {
    }

    size_t GetChunkSize()
    {
        return m_nChunkSize;
    }



    T& operator[](size_t nIndex)
    {
        // returns the element with index nIndex
        return T();
    }
};
```

Defaulted (no way to call `GetChunk`):

```
// empty argument list
template<typename T, size_t... ARGS>
class Holder : public Base<T>
{
   static_assert(sizeof...(ARGS) == 0, "Cannot instantiate a Holder type with more than one size_t");
    using Base<T>::Base;
};
```

Nondefaulted (has `GetChunk` method):

```
template<typename T, size_t nChunkSize>
class Holder<T, nChunkSize> : public Base<T, nChunkSize>
{
    using Base<T>::Base;

    public:
    T* GetChunk(size_t nChunkIndex)
    {
        // returns the address of the chunk nChunkIndex
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/417a7baa66cb28a6)

Comment: The combination of the derived class and variadic template is nifty given the OP requirements. I think this could be the closet the OP will get to what they need.

Answer (score 2):

If `nChunkSize` was a type template parameter you could use a default tag and work based on that. Since it's a non-type parameter, you could use a flag value for the default, then correct it in the class definition:

```
template<class T, size_t nChunkSize = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()>
//                         flag value ^--------------------------------^
class Holder
{
    size_t m_nSize = 0;
    size_t m_nChunkSize = 
        nChunkSize == std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() ? 1000 : nChunkSize;
        //^If the flag value was used, correct it

    T* GetChunk(size_t nChunkIndex)
    {
        //Check if the flag value was used
        static_assert(nChunkSize != std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(), 
                      "Can't call GetChunk without providing a chunk size");

        // return the address of the chunk nChunkIndex
    }
```

This will make `GetChunk` fail to compile if no default argument was passed. Of course, if you pass the max `size_t` to `Holder` then it'll silently get fixed up to `1000`, but presumably you aren't planning on passing values that high.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34d83be08177d914)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use two different classes: if they're expected to have different implementations, why stick with one single definition?

```
template<class T, size_t nChunkSize>
class ChunkHolder
{
    size_t m_nSize = 0;
    size_t m_nChunkSize = nChunkSize;

public:
    ChunkHolder(size_t nSize) : m_nSize(nSize) {}
    size_t GetChunkSize() { return m_nChunkSize; }
    // returns the address of the chunk nChunkIndex
    T* GetChunk(size_t nChunkIndex) { return nullptr; }
    // returns the element with index nIndex
    T& operator[](size_t nIndex)    { return T(); }
};

template<class T>
class UnchunkHolder
{
    size_t m_nSize = 0;

public:
    UnchunkHolder(size_t nSize) : m_nSize(nSize) {}
    // returns the address of the chunk nChunkIndex
    T& operator[](size_t nIndex)    { return T(); }
};
```

Then, we define helper functions to create one class or the other:

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE> ChunkHolder<T, SIZE>
Holder(size_t nSize) { return {nSize}; }

template <typename T>              UnchunkHolder<T>
Holder(size_t nSize) { return {nSize}; }
```

Finally, we can use it this way:

```
auto x = Holder<int, 200u>(5000u);
auto y = Holder<int>(500u);
```

`x` is a `Holder`<sup>1</sup> wit the chunk feature and `y` lacks of that feature and fails to compile the `GetChunk` call, just because the underlying type lacks of that function.

See the live demo <kbd>[here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/I3ALKQgrDX2hPvHN)</kbd>.

---

1. Well, it isn't, is a `ChunkHolder`, you can create a base class with the common implementation (`operator[]`, `...`) or use different classes; it depends on your implementation needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is essentially no standard way of knowing whether the compiler added the default value or if the user physically typed it in. By the time you code could start to differentiate, the value is already there.

A specific compiler could offer such a hook (e.g. something like `__is_defaulted(nChunkSize)`), careful examination of your compiler documentation may help, but the common compilers don't seem to offer such a facility.

---

I'm not sure the exact nature of the use case; but the "usual" option is to use partial template specialisation to differentiate between the implementations and *not to really care where the value came from* for `nChunkSize`, but *rather what the value is*.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, size_t nChunkSize = 1000>
struct A {
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct A<T, 1000> {
    A() { cout << "A() special" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    A<int, 100> a1; // prints A()
    A<int> a2; // prints A() special
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5810bf28d525ca7f). Further common details can be moved to a traits class or a base class as desired.

---

The above doesn't quite achieve what you want however. Alternatives that get you nearer the goal post would include using a "special" value that could be used to differentiate the user provided value, or to use a default. Ideally the value would be such that is it unlikely the user would use it; `0` comes to mind in this case. It still doesn't guarantee that the user would use `0`, but a `0` chunk size is unlikely in "reasonable" client code.

```
template<class T, size_t nChunkSize = 0>
class Holder
{
    size_t m_nSize = 0;
    size_t m_nChunkSize = nChunkSize == 0 ? 1000 : nChunkSize;
    // ...
```

`static_assert` can then be used to either allow the compilation of `GetChunk` or not, based on the value of `nChunkSize` - this works since `nChunkSize` is known at compile time.

```
T* GetChunk(size_t nChunkIndex)
{
    static_assert(nChunkSize != 0, "Method call invalid without client chunk size");
    // ...
```

The disadvantage is that `GetChunk` is still "visible" during development, but the compile will fail if it is invoked.

---

The closest you could get has been mentioned already, but repeated here for comparison; is to defer the implementation for the class to some `BaseHolder` and then combine that with partial template specialisation to determine if the client code used a chunk size (a value for `nChunkSize`) or not.

```
template<typename T, size_t nChunkSize /*=1000*/>
// default not provided here, it is not needed
class BaseHolder
{
    size_t m_nSize = 0;
    size_t m_nChunkSize = nChunkSize;
    // ...
};

template<typename T, size_t... ARGS>
class Holder : public Base<T, 1000>
{
    // "default" value for nChunkSize required
    // When sizeof...(ARGS) = 1, the specialisation is used
    //   when 0, the client has not provided the default
    //   when 2 or more, it is invalid usage
    static_assert(sizeof...(ARGS) == 0, "Only 1 size allowed in the client code");
    // ...
};

template<typename T, size_t nChunkSize>
class Holder<T, nChunkSize> : public Base<T, nChunkSize>
{
    // non-default chunk size used (could still be 1000)
    // includes the implementation of GetChunk
public:
    T* GetChunk(size_t nChunkIndex)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that multiple `size_t` arguments could be provided, this can be controlled at compile time with a `static_assert`; the documentation for the code should make this clear as well.

Comment: @Jarod42. So he wants to know where the user typed in the value (even if it is the same as the default), or the compiler used the default.

Comment: @Niall: Yes, that's -afaik- essentially what he is asking for.

Comment: @Pixelchemist. Sounds like an "overloaded" class definition of some sort - I see. I agree with your earlier comment, picking any compiler inserted value is indistinguishable from the use inserting the same value. He could try some "private" value or tag... it may suffer the same issues.